# My time comes wrong in India after 5:30 PM iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, utc

I am using the following code to calculate time difference

```
NSString *strTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dicTemp objectForKey:@"created_at"]];


NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dtFormatter.dateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:DATEFORMAT_TYPE];
[dtFormatter setLocale:locale];

[dtFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *dt = [dtFormatter dateFromString:strTemp];

NSDateFormatter *todayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[todayFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
todayFormatter.dateFormat = DATEFORMAT_TYPE;
[todayFormatter setLocale:locale];

NSString *strToday = [todayFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *today = [todayFormatter dateFromString:strToday];

NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:dt toDate:today options:0];
NSDateComponents *componentsMinute = [c components:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:dt toDate:today options:0];

NSInteger diffHours = components.hour;
NSInteger diffMinutes = componentsMinute.minute;
```

While sending date to server I send it in the following way:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormate setDateFormat:DATEFORMAT_TYPE];
[dateFormate setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSString *strCurrentDate = [dateFormate stringFromDate:date];
```

I get the same date from server which I send, while converting nsdate to get current date to calculate hours, I always start getting time in negative i.e. the hour difference in negative, I have noted that it happens after 5:30 PM in India, before that it is proper.

Kindly help.

Comment: Please provide sample input for `strTemp` and `strToday` that demonstrates the problem. Actual and expected results would help as well. It's impossible to reproduce problems with unknown input and output.

Comment: Your problem might be that you call `components:fromDate:toDate:..` two times. If there are 90 minutes between the two dates the first call (hour) will return 1, the second call (minute) will return 90. Use only one call and OR the components together. i.e. `NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:dt toDate:today options:0];`

Comment: 2015-03-05 10:06:41 (getting from server) , 2015-03-05 10:44:05 current date

Comment: also after this I do calculation of minutes in the following way : diffMinutes = diffMinutes - (diffHours * 60);

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the difference calculation. Let's take three examples. Dates that are 30 minutes apart, dates that are 60 minutes apart and dates that are 90 minutes apart.

---

```
NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:dt toDate:today options:0];
```

This code calculates the difference in hours between two dates. 0 for the first example (30 min), 1 for the second example (60 min), 1 for the third example (90 min).

```
NSDateComponents *componentsMinute = [c components:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:dt toDate:today options:0];
```

This code calculates the difference in minutes between two dates. It does not ignore the hours. It will give you all minutes between the dates, so the result can be bigger than 59. It's 30 for the first example (30 min), 60 for the second example (60 min), 90 for the third example (90 min).

If you think you get the minutes by using `60*diffHours + diffMinutes` your result will be wrong for every difference that is not less than 60 minutes. For 60 minutes you would calculate: `60 * 1 + 60` which is 120, and not 60. For 90 minutes you would calculate: `60 * 1 + 90` which is 150, and not 90.

I'm not sure what output you need. If you only need minutes just delete the first call.

If you need more components you should OR the NSCalendarUnits together:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:dt toDate:today options:0];

NSInteger diffHours = components.hour;
NSInteger diffMinutes = components.minute;
```

When you calculate the difference with this method, the calendar will take the bigger units into account when calculating the smaller units. Only the remainder will be used, i.e. the result will be `hour = 1 and minute = 30` for 90 minutes.